# AWS S3 + CloudFront: Fonts not loading (CORS Problem)

Tags: amazon-s3, fonts, cors

I added some custom fonts to my website and uploaded them to AWS S3 + CloudFront.

A lot of topics here describe this problem but non of them are solving my issue.

Using curl I get this output:

```
curl --head  https://cdn.mzguru.de/fonts/sourcesanspro/source-sans-pro-v12-latin-ext_latin-700.woff2
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: binary/octet-stream
Content-Length: 25348
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Tue, 22 Oct 2019 11:54:18 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000
Last-Modified: Fri, 12 Apr 2019 10:54:26 GMT
ETag: "639c2738552a0376c91e7d485e476fda"
Cache-Control: max-age=62208000
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: AmazonS3
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 bae3e24625567f5728a5caa96d6b7669.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: FRA53
X-Amz-Cf-Id: iAy-QTfuV9ZqwmaRjXE0ramVSgsZkA6MtRmQOKDSonf6I8OabrpLZA==
Age: 12818
```

Within Chrome I get this error:

```
Access to font at 'https://cdn.mzguru.de/fonts/sourcesanspro/source-sans-pro-v12-latin-ext_latin-700.woff2' from origin 'https://www.monteurzimmerguru.de' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This is the point where I do not understand the problem. The error message says: **"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present"**
But in the curl request I see this header. What is wrong?

Thank you

**EDIT**
I have attached a screenshot with the error messages.
[image: Chrome-DEV]

**EDIT 2: AWS Interface changed (2022)**
Please take a look at @James Dean post.

1.) Do I need to tick the options box?
[image]

2.) I can not find the settings you describe. I guess the UI changed in the meanwhile.

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: Just tried this request and did encounter any errors.

Comment: @AshamanKingpin What errors did you get?

Comment: @sideshowbarker I get a 200  success response.

Comment: I didn't get any at all.
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: binary/octet-stream
Content-Length: 25348
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Thu, 24 Oct 2019 12:03:19 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 12 Apr 2019 10:54:26 GMT
ETag: "639c2738552a0376c91e7d485e476fda"
Cache-Control: max-age=62208000
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: AmazonS3
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 e2bc21de81a2b5a06f939e3377436b82.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: JFK5
X-Amz-Cf-Id: odRobn0nByf4Seq2dyMXQm0Njhrn3w7HsrgwJ99ChBlvRzSmHQ9Q1w==
Age: 669

Answer (score 2):

Your S3 CORS configuration is correct based on below output:

```
>curl -vk "https://cdn.mzguru.de/fonts/sourcesanspro/source-sans-pro-v12-latin-ext_latin-700.woff2" -H "Origin: https://www.monteurzimmerguru.de"
< HTTP/2 200 
< content-type: binary/octet-stream
< content-length: 25348
< date: Thu, 24 Oct 2019 12:19:41 GMT
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< access-control-allow-methods: HEAD, GET
< access-control-max-age: 3000
< last-modified: Fri, 12 Apr 2019 10:54:26 GMT
< etag: "639c2738552a0376c91e7d485e476fda"
< cache-control: max-age=62208000
< accept-ranges: bytes
< server: AmazonS3
< x-cache: Hit from cloudfront
```

However, Chrome/Browser is making OPTIONS/Preflight request on CloudFront and options request is not allowed on cloudfront currently. Only Head and GET are allowed.

```
curl -X OPTIONS "https://cdn.mzguru.de/fonts/sourcesanspro/source-sans-pro-v12-latin-ext_latin-700.woff2" -H "Origin: https://www.monteurzimmerguru.de"
>This distribution is not configured to allow the HTTP request method that was used for this request
```

To fix this , you need to do it:

1. In the CloudFront cache behaviour, you need to allow GET,HEAD and OPTIONS
2. In Cache behaviour, cache based on selected header, you should select Origin
3. Invalidate cache once and test it again.

Comment: Thank you so much! I Did 1) and 3) and it is working now. I could not find 2). I will also add a screenshot to my original post with 1)

Comment: After I invalidated the cache it worked for a while. Unfortunately the same error came back. I guess this is a caching issue and I have to do your described bullet point number 2.  Can you describe where I can find this setting or what the exact name is?

Comment: 1. Go to Origin and Origin Groups, 2. Select Behaviors tab, 3. Select your precedence row, 4. Click Edit

Comment: @Meca : I still can't find what you describe in 2). Meanwhile the UI of AWS changed. Can you describe where we find this setting now?

Answer (score 0):

You have to update,
**Query String Forwarding and Caching to Forward all, cache based on all**
in cloudfront Cache Behavior Settings ( cloudfont -> select one -> edit )